# QGIS split feature tool produce topology gap errors while using Digitize with Curve

Tags: qgis, error, topology

I'm using QGIS to digitize an area for land-use classification. The problem occurs when I start editing and use the split feature tool to split any polygon using Digitize with Curve Tool. When I check for topology with the "must not have gaps" rule, it produces many gap errors for each curve. I do not want gaps in my features while splitting. Can anybody help me solve this problem?

[image]

As shown in the image, when I'm using Digitize with Segment tool, for example, splitting with a straight line, it does not produce gap errors. But does with the curves. Any solution to this problem is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "Curvepolygon" instead of polygon and  "Compoundcurve" instead of "lineString".